# how to check if a file is in current directory in C?

Tags: c, file, directory

How do I check if a file(input) is in the program's directory in C?
First I think I can just open the file, but I don't want user to see my other files by input something like `../important_dir/important_file`, but maybe it's OK if the user do things like `./dir1/../file1`. Which means, as long as the file is in current dir(no child dir), it's OK to open that.

Then I search around and found `readdir`, which can be used to lookup everything in current directory, but still, if current directory has a lot of files, it will be way too slow to lookup a filename every time getting a user input.

Is there any fast and secure way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think realpath should do the work.
I'll post solution tomorrow if possible.

Comment: Yes, compare what `realpath()` resolves for the file name question to the result of what `getcwd()` returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `stat()` to check for a file's status. It would return -1 if  the file in question does not exist and set `errno` to `ENOENT`.

```
char filename[] = "myfile";

struct stat s = {0};

if (!(stat(filename, &s)
{
  if (ENOENT == errno)
    perror("file does not exist.");
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to not allow user to inspect my files which are not in current directory, and it seems stat will accept a path as long as it's valid, so it will give user files like `../dir3/file4`, which isn't what I expected.